# Very heavy wordpress plugin and customization

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, performance

i have a wordpress website and with customization (cache/minify/database), is really quick in frontend, and in backend, with one exception. I use a plugin where it stores and retrieves players stats, carreers, teams etc.
When saving the team's match player's statistics, it needs 5 minutes to show the page reloaded with the data.
Also when retrieving for example team's season data, it also needs a lot of time to show them.
From what i ve seen, it is related with two of my files that do all the work. tournament_match.php, and functions.php. From hosting they said that it gets all tha database and thats why it is so slow
Here is the tournament_match file

```html
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 global $msg;
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 $tournament_id = $_GET['tid'];
 $match_id = $_GET['mid'];
 $league_type = leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($tournament_id,'league_type');

 if(isset($_POST['home_team_bonus']) or isset($_POST['away_team_bonus'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['save_tournament_match'])) { leagueengine_save_tournament_match($tournament_id,$match_id,$_POST['date_alt'],$_POST['time_alt'],$_POST['home_team_id'],$_POST['away_team_id'],$_POST['home_team_score'],$_POST['away_team_score'],$_POST['home_team_bonus'],$_POST['away_team_bonus']); } 
 } else {
  if(isset($_POST['save_tournament_match'])) { leagueengine_save_tournament_match($tournament_id,$match_id,$_POST['date_alt'],$_POST['time_alt'],$_POST['home_team_id'],$_POST['away_team_id'],$_POST['home_team_score'],$_POST['away_team_score']); }
 }
 
 if(isset($_POST['save_attributes'])) { leagueengine_save_attribute_values('tournament_match',NULL,NULL,$match_id,NULL,NULL,$tournament_id); }

 if(isset($_POST['add_event_to_match'])) { error_reporting(0); leagueengine_add_event_to_tournament_match($tournament_id,$match_id,$_POST['new_event_id'],$_POST['new_event_time'],$_POST['timeline_text'],$_POST['new_event_count'],$_POST['new_event_player_id']); error_reporting(1); }
 if(isset($_POST['save_events'])) { leagueengine_save_event_times('tournament_match',$_POST['event_time_id'],$_POST['event_time'],$_POST['event_text']); }
 if(isset($_POST['add_home_event_to_match'])){
     error_reporting(0);
     foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
         $val=intval($val);
           if(is_int($val)&&$val>0){
        $data=explode('-',$key);
         
        $playerid=$data[1];
        $eventid=$data[2];
        leagueengine_add_event_to_tournament_match2($tournament_id,$match_id,$eventid,$_POST['new_event_time'],$_POST['timeline_text'],$val,$playerid);
  
        }
     }
    error_reporting(1); 
 }
 
 
 if(isset($_POST['add_away_event_to_match'])){
     error_reporting(0);
     foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
         $val=intval($val);
           if(is_int($val)&&$val>0){
        $data=explode('-',$key);
         
        $playerid=$data[1];
        $eventid=$data[2];
        leagueengine_add_event_to_tournament_match2($tournament_id,$match_id,$eventid,$_POST['new_event_time'],$_POST['timeline_text'],$val,$playerid);
  
        }
     }
    error_reporting(1); 
 }
 
 if(isset($_POST['save_tournament_match_lineups'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['homeplayers'])) { $homeplayers = $_POST['homeplayers']; } else { $homeplayers = ''; }
  if(isset($_POST['awayplayers'])) { $awayplayers = $_POST['awayplayers']; } else { $awayplayers = ''; }
  if(isset($_POST['homesubs'])) { $homesubs = $_POST['homesubs']; } else { $homesubs = ''; }
  if(isset($_POST['awaysubs'])) { $awaysubs = $_POST['awaysubs']; } else { $awaysubs = ''; }
  leagueengine_save_tournament_match_lineups($tournament_id,$match_id,$homeplayers,$awayplayers,$homesubs,$awaysubs);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['delete_events'])) { leagueengine_delete_data('tournament_match_event',$_POST['delete_id'],'tournament',NULL,NULL,$tournament_id,$match_id); }
 
 if(isset($_POST['save_match_statistics'])) { leagueengine_save_tournament_match_statistics($tournament_id,$match_id,$_POST['tournament_match_statistic'],$_POST['home_value'],$_POST['away_value'],$_POST['att_type']); }

 if(isset($_POST['save_tournament_match_preview'])) { leagueengine_save_tournament_match_preview($tournament_id,$match_id,stripslashes_deep($_POST['match_preview'])); }
 if(isset($_POST['save_tournament_match_report'])) { leagueengine_save_tournament_match_report($tournament_id,$match_id,stripslashes_deep($_POST['match_report'])); }

 if(isset($_POST['tournament_match_swap'])) { leagueengine_tournament_match_swap($tournament_id,$match_id); }

 $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_tournament_matches';
 $match = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament_id' AND id = '$match_id'");
 $home_team_id = $match->home_team_id;
 $away_team_id = $match->away_team_id;
 $tournament = leagueengine_fetch_data_row('tournament',$tournament_id);
 $table2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_tournaments';
 $tournament_row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE data_id = '$tournament_id'");

?>

<div id="leagueengine_admin" class="<?php echo $page; ?>">

 <?php echo leagueengine_admin_header(); ?>

 <div id="leagueengine_admin_content">
  <?php if($msg) { echo $msg; } ?>

  <ul class="breadcrumbs">
   <li><a href="admin.php?page=leagueengine_data&data=competitions"><?php _e('Competitions','leagueengine');?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
   <li><a href="admin.php?page=leagueengine_tournament&id=<?php echo $tournament_id; ?>"><?php echo leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($tournament_id,'data_value') ?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
   <?php if($match->round == 'GROUP') { ?>
    <li><a href="admin.php?page=leagueengine_tournament_teams&id=<?php echo $tournament_id; ?>"><?php _e('Groups','leagueengine');?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
   <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="admin.php?page=leagueengine_tournament_knockout&id=<?php echo $tournament_id; ?>"><?php _e('Knockout','leagueengine');?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
   <?php } ?>
   <li><?php _e('Match','leagueengine');?></li>
  </ul>
  
  <?php
   if($league_type == 'players') {
    $home_emblem = leagueengine_fetch_player_emblem($match->home_team_id,20);
    $away_emblem = leagueengine_fetch_player_emblem($match->away_team_id,20,'right');
   } else {
    $home_emblem = leagueengine_fetch_team_emblem($match->home_team_id,20);
    $away_emblem = leagueengine_fetch_team_emblem($match->away_team_id,20,'right');
   }
  ?>
  
  <div class="match_masthead">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td class="home_team" style="border-top: 5px solid <?php echo leagueengine_fetch_team_colour($match->home_team_id,'primary');?>; text-align:left;width:40%;"><?php echo $home_emblem . leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($match->home_team_id,'data_value');?></td>
    <td class="score" style="text-align:center;width:20%;"><span><?php echo $match->home_team_score;?> &dash; <?php echo $match->away_team_score;?></span></td>
    <td class="away_team" style="border-top: 5px solid <?php echo leagueengine_fetch_team_colour($match->away_team_id,'primary');?>; text-align:right;width:40%;"><?php echo leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($match->away_team_id,'data_value') . $away_emblem;?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo date(leagueengine_fetch_settings('date_format_php'),strtotime($match->match_date)) . ' ' . date(leagueengine_fetch_settings('time_format_php'),strtotime($match->match_time)); ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="competition" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo '<a href="admin.php?page=leagueengine_tournament&id='.$tournament_id.'">' . leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($tournament_id,'data_value') . '</a>'; ?></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr><td colspan="100%" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom:20px;"><?php echo leagueengine_link('tournament_match&tid='.$tournament_id.'&mid='.$match->id,__('Go To Match','leagueengine'),'','','button-primary'); ?></td></tr>
   
  </table>
  </div>

  <div id="leagueengine_tabs">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#score"><?php _e('Score','leagueengine');?></a></li>
  
  
  <?php
   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_player_careers'; 
   $homeplayers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament_id' AND team_id = '$home_team_id'");
   $awayplayers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament_id' AND team_id = '$away_team_id'");
   if($homeplayers or $awayplayers && $league_type != 'players') {
  ?>
  <li><a href="#lineups"><?php _e('Lineups','leagueengine');?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if(leagueengine_data_exists('event')) { echo '<li><a href="#events">' . __('Events','leagueengine') . '</a></li>'; } ?>
  <?php if(leagueengine_statistics_exists('tournament_match')) { echo '<li><a href="#statistics">' . __('Statistics','leagueengine') . '</a></li>'; } ?>
  <?php if(leagueengine_h2h_history($match->match_date,$home_team_id,$away_team_id)) { echo '<li><a href="#history">' . __('History','leagueengine') . '</a></li>'; } ?>
  <li><a href="#report"><?php _e('Report','leagueengine');?></a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="score">

   <form action="" method="POST">
 
   <table class="form">
    <tr>
     <th style="width:20%;"><?php _e('Date/Time','leagueengine');?></th>
     <th style="width:30%;text-align:center;"><?php _e('Home','leagueengine');?></th>
     <th style="width:20%;text-align:center;"><?php _e('Score','leagueengine');?></th>
     <th style="width:30%;text-align:center;"><?php _e('Away','leagueengine');?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="date">
     <td><input type="text" class="leagueengine_datepicker" name="match_date" value="<?php echo date(leagueengine_fetch_settings('date_format_php'),strtotime($match->match_date));?>"></td>
     <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
       
       <input type="hidden" name="tournament_match_id" value="<?php echo $match->id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="home_team_id" value="<?php echo $match->home_team_id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="away_team_id" value="<?php echo $match->away_team_id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="date_alt" class="leagueengine_datepicker_alt" value="<?php echo $match->match_date;?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="time_alt" class="leagueengine_timepicker_alt" value="<?php echo $match->match_time;?>">
       
       <tr>
       <td><input type="text" class="leagueengine_timepicker" name="match_time" value="<?php echo date(leagueengine_fetch_settings('time_format_php'),strtotime($match->match_time));?>"></td>
       <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($match->home_team_id,'data_value') ;?></td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">
        <input style="width:48%;text-align:center;" type="text" name="home_team_score" value="<?php echo $match->home_team_score;?>">
        <input style="width:48%;text-align:center;" type="text" name="away_team_score" value="<?php echo $match->away_team_score;?>"> 
       </td>      
       <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($match->away_team_id,'data_value') ;?></td>
       </tr>
       
       <?php if($tournament_row->pts_bonus == 'on') { ?>
       
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td style="text-align:center;"><?php _e('Bonus Points','leagueengine');?></td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">
        <input style="width:48%;text-align:center;" type="text" name="home_team_bonus" value="<?php echo $match->home_team_bonus;?>">
        <input style="width:48%;text-align:center;" type="text" name="away_team_bonus" value="<?php echo $match->away_team_bonus;?>"> 
       </td>      
       <td style="text-align:center;"><?php _e('Bonus Points','leagueengine');?></td>
       </tr>      
       
       <?php } ?>
       
   </table>
   <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="submit" name="save_tournament_match" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save','leagueengine');?>" />
   <input style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;" type="submit" name="tournament_match_swap" class="button" value="<?php _e('Swap Teams','leagueengine');?>" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" />
   </form>

  
  </div>
  
  <?php
   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_player_careers'; 
   $homeplayers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament_id' AND team_id = '$home_team_id'");
   $awayplayers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament_id' AND  team_id = '$away_team_id'");
   if($homeplayers or $awayplayers && $league_type != 'players') {
  ?>
  <div id="lineups">
   <?php echo leagueengine_tournament_match_lineups($tournament_id,$match_id);?>   
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  
  <?php if(leagueengine_data_exists('event')) { ?>
   <div id="events">
    <?php echo leagueengine_tournament_match_events($tournament_id,$match_id);?>   
   </div>
  <?php } ?> 
  
  <?php if(leagueengine_statistics_exists('tournament_match')) { ?>
  <div id="statistics"> 
   <?php echo leagueengine_fetch_statistics('tournament_match',NULL,NULL,$tournament_id,$match_id);?> 
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if(leagueengine_h2h_history($match->match_date,$home_team_id,$away_team_id)) { ?>
  <div id="history"> 
   <?php echo leagueengine_fetch_h2h_history($match->match_date,$home_team_id,$away_team_id);?> 
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  
  <div id="report"> 
   <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="setting">
    <table class="form">
     <tr><th><?php _e('Match Report','leagueengine');?></th></tr>
    </table>
    <?php wp_editor( stripslashes_deep($match->report), 'match_report', array( 'media_buttons' => true, 'tinymce' => true, 'quicktags' => true, 'textarea_rows' => 20 )); ?>
    </div>
    <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="submit" name="save_tournament_match_report" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save','leagueengine'); ?>">
   </form>
  </div>
  
  </div> 

  </div>  

 </div>

</div>
```